# sklearn GaussianNB - bad results, [nan] probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bayesian

I'm doing some work on gender classification for a class.  I've been using SVMLight with decent results, but I wanted to try some bayesian methods on my data as well.  My dataset consists of text data, and I've done feature reduction to pare down the feature space to a more reasonable size for some of the bayesian methods.  All of the instances are run through tf-idf and then normalized (through my own code).

I grabbed the sklearn toolkit because it was easy to integrate with my current codebase, but the results I'm getting from the GaussianNB are all of one class (-1 in this case), and the predicted probabilities are all [nan].

I've pasted some relevant code; I don't know if this is enough to go on, but I'm hoping that I'm just overlooking something obvious in using the sklearn api.  I have a couple different feature sets that I've tried pushing through it, also with the same results.  Same thing too using the training set and with cross-validation.  Any thoughts?  Could it be that my feature space simply too sparse for this to work?  I have 300-odd instances, most of which have several hundred non-zero features.

```
class GNBLearner(BaseLearner):
    def __init__(self, featureCount):
        self.gnb = GaussianNB()
        self.featureCount = featureCount

    def train(self, instances, params):
        X = np.zeros( (len(instances), self.featureCount) )
        Y = [0]*len(instances)
        for i, inst in enumerate(instances):
            for idx,val in inst.data:
                X[i,idx-1] = val
            Y[i] = inst.c
        self.gnb.fit(X, Y)

    def test(self, instances, params):
        X = np.zeros( (len(instances), self.featureCount) )
        for i, inst in enumerate(instances):
            for idx,val in inst.data:
                X[i,idx-1] = val
        return self.gnb.predict(X)

    def conf_mtx(self, res, test_set):
        conf = [[0,0],[0,0]]
        for r, x in xzip(res, test_set):
            print "pred: %d, act: %d" % (r, x.c)
            conf[(x.c+1)/2][(r+1)/2] += 1
        return conf
```

Comment: This is really hard to tell without seeing the data as well, or at least a sample of it. First question, though: are you sure `GaussianNB` is appropriate? Are your features (roughly) Gaussians, i.e. normally distributed?

Comment: Good question.  I'm actually not sure what effect the tf-idf and normalization have on the distribution, but it is quite possibly not gaussian.  I honestly just grabbed this from the toolkit because it handles continuous features, so it may well be a bad choice for the data.  I'm still not sure if that explains the results I'm getting or not.

Comment: I'd missed the fact that they're tf-idf vectors. I'll whip up an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GaussianNB` is not a good fit for document classification at all, since tf-idf values are non-negative frequencies; use `MultinomialNB` instead, and maybe try `BernoulliNB`. scikit-learn comes with a [document classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html) example that, incidentally, uses tf-idf weighting using the built-in `TfidfTransformer`.

Don't expect miracles, though, as 300 samples is quite small for a training set (although for binary classification, it might just be enough to beat a "most frequent" baseline). YMMV.

**Full disclosure**: I'm one of the scikit-learn core devs and the main author of the current `MultinomialNB` and `BernoulliNB` code.

Comment: Thanks - both the Multinomial and Bernoulli classifiers worked.  In re. miracles, you may be surprised but I'm actually getting quite good results (~84% accuracy), on par with the SVM results.

Comment: @flatline: that's a good score! Given that you're doing gender classification, I expect the baseline to be just over 50%?

Comment: The baseline is a bit more biased unfortunately - 58% male - but is still a better result than I expected at the outset.  I don't think I'm going to eek anything else out of it at this point but you never know.  Scikit-learn looks like a really nice package btw, I like it a lot better than weka so far.  MultinomialNB/BernoulliNB at least can handle a much larger feature space than I thought I'd be able to do with bayesian methods.